# Как прокручивать виджеты в QScrollArea?

Tags: python, pyqt5, qss, qlayout, qscrollarea

Я попробовал добавить в `QVBoxLayout - QScrollArea` и `QScrollBar`. 
В качестве `layout` указал виджет, в котором были добавлены `player` (2 штуки).

При прокрутке виджеты множились. Если по простому, то нужно сделать `QScrollArea` и `QScrollBar`, при прокрутке которого, будут прокручиваться `player'ы`.

Как это должно выглядеть, примерно (Виджеты съехали):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что у меня получается:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот часть кода:
**Main.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
import sys, os

import player
class Main(QtWidgets.QWidget): 
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Main, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setFixedSize(750, 560)

        self.p1 = player.player_1()
        
        self.lay = QHBoxLayout(self)
        self.lay.setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0)
        
        self.scroll_area = QtWidgets.QScrollArea(self)                                        # 2
        self.scroll_area.setLayout(self.lay)
        self.scroll_area.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)

        self.scrollbar = QtWidgets.QScrollBar(Qt.Horizontal, self)                            # 3
        self.scrollbar.setMaximum(250)

        self.scrollbar.valueChanged.connect(self.sync_func)                         # 4

        self.v_layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.v_layout.addWidget(self.scroll_area)
        self.v_layout.addWidget(self.scrollbar)

    def sync_func(self):
        self.scroll_area.horizontalScrollBar().setValue(self.scrollbar.value() * 1)

        self.lay.addWidget(Sttings())
        self.lay.addWidget(player.player_1())
        self.lay.addWidget(player.player_1())


        self.transition()

    def transition(self):

        player.reputation_perem = player.reputation_perem + (player.reputation_perem / 100 * 5)
        player.money_perem = player.money_perem + player.income_perem

       #reputation_perem_2 = reputation_perem_2 + (reputation_perem_2 / 100 * 5)
       #income_perem_2 = income_perem_old_2 / 100 * (100 - (100 - reputation_perem_2))
       #money_perem_2 = money_perem_2 + income_perem_2
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)                        
    w = Main()
    w.show()

    file = QtCore.QFile("C:/for cheacher/3_mate_files/dark.qss")                              
    file.open(QtCore.QFile.ReadOnly | QtCore.QFile.Text)
    stream = QtCore.QTextStream(file)
    app.setStyleSheet(stream.readAll())

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

---

**player.py**:

```
money_perem = 0
income_perem_old = 500
income_perem = 0
credit_perem = 0
reputation_perem = 20
class player_1(QtWidgets.QWidget): 
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        global money_perem, credit_perem, reputation_perem, income_perem, income_perem_old
        super(player_1, self).__init__(parent)
    
        self.setFixedSize(350, 550)
    
    #   изображение
        self.Label_ing = QLabel('', self)
        self.img = QtGui.QPixmap('C:/py/Monopolya/polzovatel_1.png')
        self.Label_ing.setPixmap(self.img)
    
        self.Label_ing.move(75, 20)
    
    
    #   манипуляции
    
    #   Валюта
        self.PB_money = QPushButton('Валюта ₽', self)
        self.PB_money.move(15, 260)
        self.PB_money.resize(150, 25)
        self.PB_money.setStyleSheet('font: 13pt \'Arial Black\'')
    
        self.PB_money.clicked.connect(self.money_func)
    
    #   Репутация
        self.PB_reputation = QPushButton('Репутация ⓇⓅ', self)
        self.PB_reputation.move(185, 260)
        self.PB_reputation.resize(150, 25)
        self.PB_reputation.setStyleSheet('font: 13pt \'Arial Black\'')
    
        self.PB_reputation.clicked.connect(self.reputation_func)
    
    #   Кредит
        self.PB_credit = QPushButton("Кредит", self)
        self.PB_credit.move(15, 300)
        self.PB_credit.resize(150, 25)
        self.PB_credit.setStyleSheet('font: 13pt \'Arial Black\'')
    
        self.PB_credit.clicked.connect(self.credit_func)
    #   Доход
        self.PB_income = QPushButton('Доход', self)
        self.PB_income.move(185, 300)
        self.PB_income.resize(150, 25)
        self.PB_income.setStyleSheet('font: 13pt \'Arial Black\'')
    
        self.PB_income.clicked.connect(self.income_func)
    
     #   информация
    
        self.Label_Money = QLabel(self)
        self.Label_Money.move(50, 350)
        self.Label_Money.resize(400, 25)
        self.Label_Money.setStyleSheet("font: 15pt \'Arial Black\'")
    
        self.Label_reputation = QLabel(self)
        self.Label_reputation.move(50, 400)
        self.Label_reputation.resize(400, 25)
        self.Label_reputation.setStyleSheet("font: 15pt \'Arial Black\'")
    
        self.Label_income = QLabel(self)
        self.Label_income.move(50, 450)
        self.Label_income.resize(400, 25)
        self.Label_income.setStyleSheet("font: 15pt \'Arial Black\'")
    
        self.Label_credit = QLabel(self)
        self.Label_credit.move(50, 500)
        self.Label_credit.resize(400, 25)
        self.Label_credit.setStyleSheet("font: 15pt \'Arial Black\'")
    
        self.t = QtCore.QTimer(interval=100)
        self.t.timeout.connect(self.update_info)
        self.t.start()
    
    def update_info(self):
        global money_perem, reputation_perem, income_perem, credit_perem, income_perem_old
    
        income_perem = income_perem_old / 100 * (100 - (100 - reputation_perem))
    
        self.Label_Money.setText('Деньги: ' + str(money_perem / 1000000) + ' ' + "млн ₽")
        self.Label_reputation.setText('Репутация: ' + str(reputation_perem) + ' ' + 'ⓇⓅ')
        self.Label_income.setText('Доход: ' + str(income_perem / 1000) + ' ' + '(' + str(income_perem_old / 1000) + ')' + ' тыс ₽')
        self.Label_credit.setText('Кредит: ' + str(credit_perem / 1000000) + ' ' + 'млн ₽')
    
    
    
    def credit_func(self):
        self.cr = credit()
        self.cr.show()
    def money_func(self):
        self.m = money()
        self.m.show()
    def reputation_func(self):
        self.rep = reputation()
        self.rep.show()
    def income_func(self):
        self.incom = income()
        self.incom.show()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)                        
    file = QtCore.QFile("C:/for cheacher/3_mate_files/dark.qss")                              
    file.open(QtCore.QFile.ReadOnly | QtCore.QFile.Text)
    stream = QtCore.QTextStream(file)
    app.setStyleSheet(stream.readAll())

    w = player_1()
    w.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Если вам действительно нужна помощь, предоставьте пожалуйста МИНИМАЛЬНО-ВОСПРОИЗВОДИМЫЙ пример, который демонстрирует проблему. И объясните пожалуйста лучше, что вы хотите сделать.

Comment: S. Nick, готово

Comment: что вы хотите сделать ?

Comment: Описать сложно, но я попробую. Решил сделать экономическую игру (монополия, только программа). планируется, что у человека, который будет проводить игру, будет 'админ - панель' игры. Но получается так, что окно будет большое. Поэтому пришла идея сделать с помощью ScrollArea, но не получилось

Comment: пока ничего не понял, но интуитивно чувствую, что идея с `ScrollArea` не правильная. Глобальные переменные - это ЗЛО! Чему равны значения переменных `money_perem, credit_perem, reputation_perem, income_perem, income_perem_old` при инициализации ? Допишите из значения в описании вопроса.

Comment: money_perem = 0;
income_perem_old = 500;
income_perem = 0;
credit_perem = 0;
reputation_perem = 20

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`class Player_1` - теперь под управлением менеджера компоновки.

**`Никаких глобальных переменных`**.

Поменяйте `изображение` и `dark.qss` на свои.
Я отметил строки, которые поменял. Пробуйте:

```
import sys                                             #, os
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import *

#import player
class Player_1(QtWidgets.QWidget): 
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
#-        global money_perem, credit_perem, reputation_perem, income_perem, income_perem_old
        super(Player_1, self).__init__(parent)
        
        self.money_perem = 0; 
        self.income_perem_old = 500; 
        self.income_perem = 0; 
        self.credit_perem = 0; 
        self.reputation_perem = 20

        self.setFixedSize(350, 550)

        #   изображение
        self.Label_ing = QLabel('', self)
        self.Label_ing.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap('head3.png').scaled(140, 140))       # !

        #?   манипуляции

        #   Валюта
        self.PB_money = QPushButton('Валюта ₽', minimumHeight=50)
        self.PB_money.clicked.connect(self.money_func)
        #   Репутация
        self.PB_reputation = QPushButton('Репутация ⓇⓅ', minimumHeight=50)
        self.PB_reputation.clicked.connect(self.reputation_func)
        #   Кредит
        self.PB_credit = QPushButton("Кредит", minimumHeight=50)
        self.PB_credit.clicked.connect(self.credit_func)
        #   Доход
        self.PB_income = QPushButton('Доход', minimumHeight=50)
        self.PB_income.clicked.connect(self.income_func)
        #   информация
        self.Label_Money = QLabel(self)
        self.Label_reputation = QLabel(self)
        self.Label_income = QLabel(self)
        self.Label_credit = QLabel(self)
# ++ vvv
        self.grid_layout = QGridLayout(self)    
        self.grid_layout.addWidget(self.Label_ing, 0, 0, 2, 2, alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.grid_layout.addWidget(self.PB_money, 2, 0)
        self.grid_layout.addWidget(self.PB_reputation, 2, 1)
        self.grid_layout.addWidget(self.PB_credit, 3, 0)
        self.grid_layout.addWidget(self.PB_income, 3, 1) 
        self.grid_layout.addWidget(self.Label_Money, 4, 0, 1, 2)  
        self.grid_layout.addWidget(self.Label_reputation, 5, 0, 1, 2) 
        self.grid_layout.addWidget(self.Label_income, 6, 0, 1, 2) 
        self.grid_layout.addWidget(self.Label_credit, 7, 0, 1, 2) 
# ++ ^^^
        self.t = QtCore.QTimer(interval=1000)                     # 100
        self.t.timeout.connect(self.update_info)
        self.t.start()

    def update_info(self):
#-        global money_perem, reputation_perem, income_perem, credit_perem, income_perem_old
        self.income_perem = self.income_perem_old / 100 * (100 - (100 - self.reputation_perem))
        self.Label_Money.setText('Деньги: ' + str(self.money_perem / 1000000) + ' ' + "млн ₽")
        self.Label_reputation.setText('Репутация: ' + str(self.reputation_perem) + ' ' + 'ⓇⓅ')
        self.Label_income.setText('Доход: ' + str(self.income_perem / 1000) + ' ' + '(' + str(self.income_perem_old / 1000) + ')' + ' тыс ₽')
        self.Label_credit.setText('Кредит: ' + str(self.credit_perem / 1000000) + ' ' + 'млн ₽')

    def credit_func(self):
        self.cr = credit()
        self.cr.show()
        
    def money_func(self):
        self.m = money()
        self.m.show()
        
    def reputation_func(self):
        self.rep = reputation()
        self.rep.show()
        
    def income_func(self):
        self.incom = income()
        self.incom.show()
        

class Main(QtWidgets.QWidget): 
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Main, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setFixedSize(700, 600)        # 750, 560
#
        self.p1 = Player_1()
        self.p2 = Player_1()                                                        # +
        self.p3 = Player_1()                                                        # +
        self.stting = QLabel("админ - панель")                                      # ? Sttings()
        self.stting.setFixedSize(350, 550)
# ++ vvv
        self.widget = QWidget()
        self.lay = QHBoxLayout(self.widget)   # self
        self.lay.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)        
        self.lay.addWidget(self.stting)
        self.lay.addWidget(self.p1) #Player_1())
        self.lay.addWidget(self.p2) #Player_1())
        self.lay.addWidget(self.p3) #Player_1())
# ++ ^^^
        self.scroll_area = QtWidgets.QScrollArea(self) 
#-        self.scroll_area.setLayout(self.lay)
        self.scroll_area.setWidget(self.widget)
        self.scroll_area.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)

        self.scrollbar = QtWidgets.QScrollBar(Qt.Horizontal, self)  
# ?        self.scrollbar.setMaximum(250)
        self.scrollbar.setMaximum(self.scroll_area.horizontalScrollBar().maximum())
        self.scrollbar.valueChanged.connect(self.sync_func)   

        self.v_layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.v_layout.addWidget(self.scroll_area)
        self.v_layout.addWidget(self.scrollbar)

    def sync_func(self):
        self.scroll_area.horizontalScrollBar().setValue(self.scrollbar.value())    # ?  * 1
        self.transition()

    def transition(self):
#        player.reputation_perem = player.reputation_perem + (player.reputation_perem / 100 * 5)
#        player.money_perem = player.money_perem + player.income_perem
        self.p1.reputation_perem = self.p1.reputation_perem + (self.p1.reputation_perem / 100 * 5)
        self.p1.money_perem = self.p1.money_perem + self.p1.income_perem

       #reputation_perem_2 = reputation_perem_2 + (reputation_perem_2 / 100 * 5)
       #income_perem_2 = income_perem_old_2 / 100 * (100 - (100 - reputation_perem_2))
       #money_perem_2 = money_perem_2 + income_perem_2
       
       
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)  
    app.setFont(QFont("Arial Black", 12, QFont.Bold)) 

    w = Main()
    w.show()

#    file = QtCore.QFile("C:/for cheacher/3_mate_files/dark.qss") 
    file = QtCore.QFile("D:/_Qt/Python-Examples/_PyQt5/Style/BreezeStyleSheets/dark.qss")    # !
    file.open(QtCore.QFile.ReadOnly | QtCore.QFile.Text)
    stream = QtCore.QTextStream(file)
    app.setStyleSheet(stream.readAll())

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Огромное спасибо!

Comment: @5478512 пожалуйста